# How to load the PyQt5 UI file from resources?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to load the `window.ui` file from `resources_rc.py`

I tried:

```py
import resources_rc


class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()

        uic.loadUi(':/newPrefix/window.ui', self)
```

But

`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: ':/newPrefix/window.ui'`

[PyQt: How do I load a ui file from a resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832610/pyqt-how-do-i-load-a-ui-file-from-a-resource)
didn't help.

Comment: The argument is invalid because the string path needs to be a *real* OS path, while that is just a resource one. The post you linked shows exactly what you want in its question: create a QFile with the resource path, open it, and use it as first argument of `loadUi()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
Thanks to [musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante)

```py
stream = QtCore.QFile(":/newPrefix/window.ui")
stream.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
uic.loadUi(stream, self)
stream.close()
```